# Back button in NSPopover

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

Apple uses these rather cool looking custom (?) buttons in multi page `NSPopovers`:

[image]

You can see them when you highlight a word and choose "Look up..." in an NSTextView.

Anybody knows whether these are available to us mere mortals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard buttons with that appearance. The easiest way to get a similar appearance would just be to use a standard `NSButton` with an image.

Comment: If you're looking for inspiration, you can maybe find the image using https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Comment: @ChristianBeer: That only extracts images from the iOS platform, not Mac.

Comment: D'Oh! You're right! Overread NS and just read Popover… Sorry.